# ERROR : Failed to resolve : com.google.firebase-core:16.0.2 Affected Modules : app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase-auth : 16.0.2'
Implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.2
```

Error is shown here also:

> ERROR : Failed to resolve : com.google.firebase-core:16.0.2 Affected Modules : app

Comment: That's a **very** old version of firebase-auth.  Consider updating to something more recent.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 0):

Update the dependencies to the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
```

Also migrare to `androidx`:

> Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
>
> Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
>
> Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).